# Opening zsh in vscode gives me error (core parameters have unexpectedly changed)

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When opening zsh on the normal terminal I have no errors, while when I open it on vscode I get this:

```
z4h: core parameters have unexpectedly changed

Expected:

  ZDOTDIR=/Users/*******

Found:

  ZDOTDIR=/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh

Restore the parameters or restart Zsh with exec zsh.

Restore the parameters or restart Zsh with exec zsh.
```

I installed zsh with z4h and for a while it worked well. Then it started showing this error randomly.

PS: I tried restarting Zsh with exec zsh.

**EDIT:**
Tried to create the folder "/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh" and paste the files in /Users/******** in there as suggested but it still didn't work. Then in that folder, in the .zshrc I tried editing a part of it from this

```
if [[ "$VSCODE_INJECTION" == "1" ]]; then
    if [[ $options[norcs] = off  && -f $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc ]]; then
        VSCODE_ZDOTDIR=$ZDOTDIR
        ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
        . $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
        ZDOTDIR=$VSCODE_ZDOTDIR
    fi

    if [[ -f $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history ]]; then
        HISTFILE=$USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history
    fi
fi
```

to this:

```
if [[ "$VSCODE_INJECTION" == "1" ]]; then
    if [[ $options[norcs] = off  && -f $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc ]]; then
        VSCODE_ZDOTDIR=$ZDOTDIR
        ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
        . $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
        ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR
    fi

    if [[ -f $USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history ]]; then
        HISTFILE=$USER_ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history
    fi
fi
```

When in vscode the first time I opened a new terminal it worked, but after that the file was again the same as the fist one and creating another terminal would give the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug on the VS code side and a fix has been made available in the insider build and will be available to the public shortly and can be tracked at [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157128).

For now, this can be solved by setting `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to `false` in settings.json file or by disabling this option in settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message shows vscode executes zsh from `/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh`.
But no z4h's setting there. A workaround as below:

1. Backup if the `/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh/.zshenv` and `/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh/.zshrc` that existed in the path
2. Copy `/Users/*******/.zshenv` and `/Users/*******/.zshrc` to `/var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh/`
3. Restart the terminal on vscode

Comment: I'm not able to find that path, where can I find it?

Comment: If the path can't be found. You can create the same path with `mkdir -p </var/folders/0f/**************/T/vscode-zsh/>` and copy `.zshenv` and `.zshrc` from your home directory.

Comment: I did that, but it is not working... Could it be because there are two more files on that folder? (.zslogin and .zprofile)

Comment: Yes, you should copy all files from the two folders `.zshenv` and `.zshrc`.

Comment: I did that but it still didn't work

Comment: I tried to edit the .zshrc in that folder I created, and I set ZDOTDIR=$VSCODE_ZDOTDIR to ZDOTDIR=$USER_ZDOTDIR, and the first time I opened the terminal it worked, but then that file is back like before and it is now the same as before, and when I create a new terminal I get the same error again

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work. Another way that execute zsh with the same path. You need to reset the environment variable `ZIM_HOME` to the Expected path.

1. In vscode `CMD+Shift+P`
2. Choose `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
3. Add a keyname `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx`
4. Add the following value to this key.

   ```
   {
     "zsh": {
         "path": "/bin/zsh",
         "ZDOTDIR": "/Users/*******"
     }
   }
   ```
5. It would look like as below finally. [updated] the env var in your case
   is `ZDOTDIR`

   ```
   {
    ...
     "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "zsh": {
                "path": "/bin/zsh",
                "ZDOTDIR": "/Users/*******"
        }
     }
   ...
   }
   ```
6. Restart the terminal.

Comment: This didn't work neither

Comment: try to set `ZDOTDIR` in the settings.json.